# How to instantiate root UINavigationController in Swift?

Tags: swift, firebase

I have a Firebase application written programmatically with the root view controller embedded in a UINavigationController.

*SceneDelegate.swift*

```
guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
window?.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: HomeController())
```

In the application, the first thing that happens in `HomeController` is a check to see if the user is logged in, if not it presents a separate ViewController called `LoginController`, which is also embedded in a UINavigationController, in order to navigate between a Register and the Login View Controller.

*HomeController.swift (This is what is executed if Firebase says the user is not logged in)*

```
let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: LoginController())
nav.isModalInPresentation = true
nav.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
self.present(nav, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

However, the method in `LoginController` that logs the user in and configures the `HomeController` doesn't work properly.
This is how I usually instantiate the rootViewController when it's not embedded in a UINavigationController:

```
guard let controller = UIApplication.shared.windows.filter({$0.isKeyWindow}).first?.rootViewController as? HomeController else { return }
```

It shows up as `nil` when it's embedded in a UINavigationController.

My question is: How do I create an instance of `HomeController` to call it's functions to configure the UI, etc. after dismissing the `LoginController`?

Just writing `let homeController = HomeController()`, then calling `homeController.configureUI()` doesn't work.

**EDIT:**

I was able to access the method from the `HomeController` with this:

```
let controller = self.navigationController?.viewControllers[0] as? HomeController
controller?.configure()
```

But I don't think this is a good solution.

Comment: Why are you embedding each controller separately in `UINavigationController` when presenting? Won't everything work with a single `navigationController`?

Comment: @PGDev I've tried both ways, with two UINavigationControllers and with just one. Both times, I'm unable to call my functions from `HomeController` to configure everything once I either dismiss or pop back to the root view controller. My code sample to grab it, the guard let controller... returns, since it comes back as nil. It works for all my other applications except for when the root view controller is embedded in a UINavigationController.